# Friend picker as a share to friends button

Tags: kik

I'm trying to create a "share" button for the app that users will be able to pick friends up from the the list and message them in one shot, now I saw the `kik.pickUsers()` function, I tried something like

```
kik.pickUsers(function (users) {
    if(users) {
        users.forEach(function (user) {
            kik.send(user.username, {
                title : 'TITLE GOES HERE'
            });
        });
    }
});
```

but seems like it lets to share it with only one friend, is there any better way to do it ? or am I missing anything ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no way to message multiple users in a single API call yet.